# How to create seprate mobile website using jquery mobile

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

Hi im developing a mobile website using jquery, i just wanted to check whether i can create device specific versions for iphone and android. if its possible please help me with some links where i can find examples. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use phone gap framework for developing the website's for compatible for all platforms using html5. look at this web site [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) going to useful for you.